# Pass image from one .jsp to another .jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am learning JSP and I can't find an answer to the following question:

I want to upload the image file in one page, pass it to another and show it there like (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081998/how-to-pass-image-from-one-jsp-to-another-jsp) question):

**first.jsp**

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="save()" action="second.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="openFile" onchange="reloadPreview()">
    <canvas name="preview"></canvas>
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
<script>
    function reloadPreview(){
        var preview = document.getElementsByName("preview")[0];
        var file    = document.getElementsByName("openFile")[0].files[0];
        var reader  = new FileReader();
        var picture = new Image;

        reader.onloadend = function () {
            picture.src = reader.result;
            preview.width = picture.width;
            preview.height = picture.height;
            var context = preview.getContext("2d");
            context.drawImage(picture, 0, 0);
            dataUrl = preview.toDataURL();
        };

        if (file) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
   }

    function save() {
        window.location = "second.jsp?imgUrl="+dataUrl;
        document.getElementById("form").submit();
    }

   var dataUrl;
</script>
```

1) What should I do to access canvas content from `second.jsp`?

2) Can I access `openFile` file without uploading it to `canvas` (for example if file is not an image)?

Comment: The process is 1) You upload the file to your server in a manner that it is accessible by an URL and 2) You pass that URL somehow (session attribute, database, whatever) to the second JSP so you can use it to generate the proper HTML/JS code.

Answer (score -1):

Source:

```
<%session.setAttribute("Down1","download.png");%>
<td>Image: </td>
<td><img src="download.png" width="516" height="516" alt="Down" name="Down1"/></td>
```

Destination:

```
<td><img src="download.png" width="516" height="516" alt="Down" name="Down1"/></td>
```

Comment: This answer does not attempt to answer the two questions explicitly mentioned in the question.